# Hovering over element using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate some stuff on https://translate.google.com. The problem is that I fail when it comes to the point when I need to press the language swap button.

I'm defining the swapping button as `swap_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ow23"]/div/span/button')))`

When I try to click it using `swap_button.click()` nothing seems to happen until I hover over the button manually.

I've also tried using `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(swap_button).perform()` to simulate the hover, though even with `time.sleep(5)` it doesn't seem to make any difference.

As an alternative for `swap_button.click()` I tried using `swap_button.send_keys(Key.ENTER)` but the problem was still remaining.

I do not know if I am just not able to get it working or if Google has done something to prevent things like web-automation from happening.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try waiting until the button is clickable and fix its locator:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aCQag .VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe.yHy1rc.eT1oJ.q7sDqe.lRTpdf.U2dVxe")))
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".aCQag .VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe.yHy1rc.eT1oJ.q7sDqe.lRTpdf.U2dVxe")
elem.click()
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it seems to work now. Why does it make a difference if I use XPATH or CSS_SELECTOR though?

Comment: It's only a matter of taste. I could find xpath as well. But in this case it will be too long. IN the case of css selectors you just put a dot before class name.

Comment: @Dom `XPATH` engines are different in each browser, and so it makes them unreliable. Additionally, performance-wise `CSS_SELECTORS` have advantage over `XPATH`.

Comment: Alright, I understand. One last question, is there any other way to copy the css_selectors than doing it manually or getting an extension for it?

Comment: I think there should be some browser extensions, but I don't use any.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think it should be :

```
wait(your_driver_name, some_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ow23"]/div/span/button')))
```

Comment: This isn't it. Above the given code I have written `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)`